# Known and described subclasses of Context-Free Grammars class

Tags: fl.formal-languages, grammars, context-free

I'm looking for various researches which consider specific subclasses of Context-Free Grammar class, i.e. some specific described cases, which differ from well-known:

- deterministic/non-deterministic
- ambiguous/unambiguous
- regular/non-regular

As an example of such "non-standard" subclasses are *Visibly pushdown grammar* described [here](http://dept-info.labri.fr/~fleury/Formation_Doctorale_2006/papers/AM04.pdf). Any additional examples will be much appreciated.

**More specifically**, I'm wondering, are any described subclasses which can help distinguish this two very similar cases?

$G_1$:

$S\rightarrow aD$, $S\rightarrow cD$

$D\rightarrow abc$, $D\rightarrow abDc$

$G_2$:

$S\rightarrow aD$, $S\rightarrow cD$

$D\rightarrow abc$, $D\rightarrow abDc$, $D\rightarrow aDb$, $D\rightarrow aDc$

It is clear that both of them are unambiguous non-determ. CFG, and $\mathcal{L}(G_1)\subset\mathcal{L}(G_2)$. But these are common properties, I'm looking for specific differences.

Comment: Aside: are you sure that $G_1$ is non-deterministic? Why can't a $LR(0)$ parser reduce $abc$ or $abDc$ to $D$ every time it shifts a $c$?

Comment: Sorry, why it should (or can) shift *c*? $abDc$ makes this grammar non-regular (produces $(ab)^k abc (c)^k$).

Comment: I agree that the language of $D$ isn't regular. However, deterministic languages are a much broader class, encompassing all the $LR$ languages.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Density* might be interesting concept for you. The density function is defined as
$$\delta_L(n) := |L\cap \Sigma^n|,$$

where $\Sigma^n$ denotes the set of all strings of length $n$ over $\Sigma$.

Your first language seems to have density values of only 0 and 1 while the second goes up to 3. So the first is 1-slender, the second is not following the terminology of  [Lucian Ilie's work](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0304397598002667).

Answer (score 6):

Your two grammars seem very similar. They are both linear grammars in two non-terminals. (Morally one, really -- in both examples the language of S is contained in the language semiring generated by the language of D.)

It might be worth looking at your example in terms of the [Chomsky-Schützenberger theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chomsky%E2%80%93Sch%C3%BCtzenberger_representation_theorem). The theorem's statement for the two grammars in question is pretty trivial, but you'll probably find that the brace-pair alphabet for the smallest Dyck language of which $L(G_1)$ is a homomorphic image is smaller than the that for $L(G_2)$. (At a glance, I'm counting 3 and 5 respectively.)